# How to pass an actionlink's results to a partialview placeholder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

Okay, so in my page I have a list of links:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Recruitments", new { Id = item.Id })
    <br />
}
```

And what I want is for the partialview to return somewhere else on the page, in a placeholder I've set aside.

Is this possible? Or do I have to use jquery ajax calls instead somewhere?

Comment: your question doesn't make sense...  you want the result of the action link during the page creation?

Comment: I want the result of the actionlink when the link is clicked. So if I click the link, the partial page result replaces another part of the page with the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can **@Ajax.ActionLink** in asp.net mvc, it has different overloads you can use according to your requirements here is the code:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("ActionName", // action name
                "Recruitments", //controller name
                 new { Id = item.Id }, // route values
                 new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", //HttpMethod Get or Post
                 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,  // Replace content of container
                 UpdateTargetId = "Container", // id of element in which partial view will load 
                 OnComplete = "Completed();" }) // js function to be executed when ajax call complete


<div id="Container">
</div>

<script>

function Completed()
{
alert("completed");
}
</script>
```

Comment: This seems to still load the partialview in a whole different page, instead of injecting it into the application. Additionally, the Completed() method is never even called. Why would this be? My Action return result is a PartialView

Comment: Seems I was missing jquery unobtrusive, which rectifies the problem.

Comment: yes for Ajax Helpers, jquery unobtrusive should be included.

Answer (score 1):

I did had a problem with partial for your problem post some code so I understand your problem.

Either you should use a razor helper, either you simply use jquery to manipulate the dom.

note that jquery is pretty simple

```
$("#selectorOnYourPlaceHolder").html($("#selectorOnYourLinks").html());
$("#selectorOnYourLinks").html("")
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to do this with Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET", url: "somePageOrHandler.aspx", data: "var1=4343&var2=hello",
        success: function(data)
            {
                $('#someDivInPlaceHolder').html( data);
            }
         });
```

Comment: So then @Html.Partial would only be good for non dynamic execution?

Comment: yes, it is used only for server time page creation, not browser time events.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I like the approach of the @Ajax.Actionlink that was offered, which is more akin to what I was trying to accomplish. Thanks for the answer though! That's another good way to do it that I'm still learning.